# method in class controller not found : BadMethodCallException

Tags: laravel-5.7

I'm learning laravel. I'd just like to display links coming from my mysql table dynamically , I do not understand where my mistake comes from. I have this error:

> BadMethodCallException Method App\Http\Controllers\NiceActionController::getHome does not exist.

the controller
`app\Http\Controllers\NiceActionController.php`:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use \Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\NiceAction;

    class NiceActionController extends Controller
    {
        public function getHome()
        {
            $actions = NiceAction::all();
            return view('home',['actions'=>$actions]);
        }
    }
```

in the route file
`routes\web.php`:

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>['web']],function(){
    Route::get('/',[
        'uses'=>'NiceActionController@getHome',
        'as'=>'home'
    ]);

Route::group(['prefix' => 'do'], function () {

    Route::get('/{action}/{name?}', [
        'uses'=>'NiceActionController@getNiceAction',
        'as' =>'niceaction'
    ]);
});

});
```

and in the view :

`views\home.blade.php`

```
@foreach ($actions as $action)
            <a href="{{ route('niceaction',['action'=>lcfirst($action->name)])}}">
                {{$action->name}}
              </a>
            @endforeach
```

I have model but nothing in for now

`app\NiceAction.php`

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class NiceAction extends Model
{
    //
}
```

thanks for your help

Comment: What route are you calling when you get this mistake?

Comment: Hi, the only possible reason is that you accidentally moved the App/NiceAction to another folder, make sure this file is in the root of App.